# Loop through a map containing a String and another map

Tags: java, dictionary, foreach, hashmap

I declare my map like so:

`Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> junctions = new HashMap<>();`

and fill it with data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String[] coordinates = s.nextLine().split(" ");
            junctions.put(i, new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
            junctions.get(i).put(Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]), Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]));
        }
```

But I'm unable to print it out, or use the contents of it.

I have tried it like this:

```
for (Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> m : junctions.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + "/" + m.getValue());
        }
```

I have also tried using `junctions.values()` instead of `junctions.entrySet()`

What do I need to do?

Comment: Your example code looks a lot like you can replace the Map on the top level with a list, so e. g. `List<Map<Integer, Integer>>`. Or even better something like `List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> e : junctions.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + "/" + e.getValue());
}
```

or

```
for (Map<Integer, Integer> m : junctions.values()) {
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

depending on what you want to print.